# As in Kohana 3.3 add a rule on the fly?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

As in Kohana 3.3 add a rule on the fly? Ie eg before saving the model User, if a certain condition is fulfilled, you need to add a rule city_id model must not be empty, try this:

```
if (Arr::get($data, 'val') > 0){
                    ORM::factory('User')->rules(array('city_id, array(array('not_empty'), array('digit'))));
                }

            try {
                $this->user->update_user($data);
            } catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) {
                $errors = $e->errors('Validation');
           }
```

Bypasses in any case, i.e. usually it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are even trying to use the wrong:

```
ORM::factory('User')->rules(array ('city_id, array (array (' not_empty '), array (' digit '))));
```

As a minimum, there should be as follows:

```
ORM::factory('User')->rules(array ('city_id => array (array (' not_empty '), array (' digit '))));
```

Without intervention in the code does not work, I will explain ...

In the ORM:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array ();
}
```

Who we override in the model.

Even a record implies a redefinition of what is already in the model.

```
ORM::factory('User')->rules(array ('city_id => array (array (' not_empty '), array (' digit '))));
```

But neither of which you can add the required method Class ORM:

```
public function addRules($a2){
    $a1 = $ this->rules();
    return array_merge_recursive ($a1,$a2);
}
```

Then we get the following:

```
ORM::factory('User')->addRules(array ('city_id => array (array (' not_empty '), array (' digit '))));
```

Cool, but it does not work, as in:

```
/**
     * Initializes validation rules, and labels
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _validation()
    {
        // Build the validation object with its rules
        $this->_validation = Validation::factory($this->_object)
            ->bind(':model', $this)
            ->bind(':original_values', $this->_original_values)
            ->bind(':changed', $this->_changed);

        foreach ($this->rules() as $field => $rules)
        {
            $this->_validation->rules($field, $rules);
        }

        // Use column names by default for labels
        $columns = array_keys($this->_table_columns);

        // Merge user-defined labels
        $labels = array_merge(array_combine($columns, $columns), $this->labels());

        foreach ($labels as $field => $label)
        {
            $this->_validation->label($field, $label);
        }
    }
```

It still causes `rules()`, and this is that the model ...

You can continue the thought, but I advise you to take advantage of **external validation**.